# How to pass permissions to Broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

In the MainActivity my app gets permission `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.
Then it sets an Alarm

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 101, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, 5000, pendingIntent);
```

When then receiver is triggered, it doesn't sees that the permission was given:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location;
    if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Not Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
}
```

I don't want the app asking User again for permission, how do I achieve that?

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

This lines means permission is not `granted`. You need to ask for permission you write wrong `condition`. Your condition should look like this

```
if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Not Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }else{

        Toast.makeText(context, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
```